# How can I set a variable after a fetch call?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I know this is probably simple, but I can't figure it out with plain javascript. I am doing a fetch call and setting a variable right after it, which I know is not possible without a callback or ES7 await, etc. The problem is I have to use ES6 or earlier. How do I set a variable on the result right after I run the fetch call?

```
postData(baseUrl)
    .then(data => 
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("QuestionsForValidation", (data))) // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

function postData(url) {
    // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
            method: "GET", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            mode: "cors",
            // include, *same-origin, omit
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "x-api-token": Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("APIToken"),
                "accept": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json()); // parses response to JSON
}


var JSONString = JSON.stringify(Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData("QuestionsForValidation").result)
```

It is not setting the variable because javascript is asynchronous. I want the variable to be set from the result of the fetch call. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: that is what promises are for.... change your logic

Comment: `response.json()` doesn't resolve to the JSON string, it parses the JSON string and resolves to the object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: The variable should be set; you're reading it too early.

Comment: You may set the value inside then()

Comment: You have to use it inside the `.then()` callback, just like when you call `setEmbeddedData`.